# I'll be going/I'll go

Tags: present-continuous

What is the exact use of an –ing form in this sentence? I usually say "I'll go", "I have to go", "I must go". Why say "I'll be going", "I must be going", "I have to be going?"

> Shall I pick up the laundry for you? Oh, no, don’t make a special journey. It’s OK. **I'll be going to** the shops anyway.

Answer (score 1):

*I'll [I shall] be going to the shops anyway* means "I am already planning to go to the shops". You could also say *I'm going to the shops anyway* (present referring to the future).

The continuous (progressive) tense usually means that an action is ongoing, but this is a special use of *I'm going to* meaning that you plan or expect to do something in the future.

*I'll go to the shops* doesn't carry the same implication of an existing plan.

Comment: I'm a bit cunfused by the use of an –ing form. Is it similar to "I'll be going out to eat tonight"? The progressive is used to talk about an ongoing action (in progress).

Comment: _I'll_ here is short for _I shall_, so, yes, it's the same whether you are planning to go to the shops or to have a meal out. I have edited my answer.

Comment: What about *I have to be going*? Why is the –ing form used rather than "I have to go?"

Comment: Another peculiar English idiom. When parting from friends or leaving someone's house, _I have to be going now_ sounds less abrupt than _I have to go now_ (you are preparing to leave rather than walking out of the door). See [this](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/its-getting-late-i-have-to-be-going-go-now.2944393/).